# Error on running transaction with multiple entity groups through nosetests

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nose

I am building an application with Python 2.7 using the Google App Engine framework.
To test my application I have a several tests that are run through nosetests making use of the nosegae plugin. I run them with the following command:

```
nosetests --with-gae --gae-lib-root=/usr/local/google_appengine/ -w . -w */test/ -v
```

In the model layer of my application, I have the need to run several database operations that affect multiple entity groups inside the same transaction. I do this by making use of the run_in_transaction_options function of the db package:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#run_in_transaction

Unfortunately, when running my test suites, I get the following error in those testcases that try to run such transaction:

> BadRequestError: transactions on multiple entity groups only allowed
>   with the High Replication datastore

I cannot find any flag in nosetests that makes it possible to enable the HRD.

I am wondering if it is possible at all to run HRD from nosetests and if so, how it can be set up?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would highly suggest you to switch from **db** to **ndb**, where you can use [cross group transactions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions).

To simulate the HRD, you can add this part to the `setUp` function of your tests, from [Writing High Replication Datastore tests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting#Python_Writing_High_Replication_Datastore_tests):

```
# Create a consistency policy that will simulate the High Replication consistency model.
self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=0)

# Initialize the datastore stub with this policy.
self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)
```